# While importing the URL file from my app to the main URL file (Django)

Tags: python, django

#I am trying to import the URL file from my app to the main file#
#main url file#

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import  path,include
from django.http import  HttpResponse




urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include ('base.links'))
]
```

the error i am getting:
cannot import name 'path' from partially initialized module 'base.links' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\studybudy\base\links.py)

#the url file in my app#

```
from base.links import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(' ',views.home),
    path('room',views.room),
]
```

#the views file in my app#

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('home123')

def room(request):
    return HttpResponse('Room')
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually realized the error was in the base file i should have put django.urls instead of base.links